# More True to Life?

Tags: grammar

I know that "truer to life" is correct. Is "more true to life" also correct? If so, when would we use each?
E.g. the experiment produces more true to life results.

Comment: In general "more true to life" feels more natural to me, but in your example sentence it could be interpreted as "[produces more] [true to life] [results]" rather than "[produces] [more true to life] [results]".

Comment: @nnnnnn To me as well, but since we don't use "more true" I thought here "more" could go for "true" instead of the whole clause of "true to life", so maybe it's grammatically wrong to say "more true to life"? I'm not sure. I hope someone can explain why "more true to life" would be correct or wrong. Also how would you put my example in a way that's not ambiguous? I was just trying to make up an example that would make you doubt which one would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instinct is correct.  Some people (of whom I am one) dislike the comparative 'truer' because truth is strictly speaking absolute:  a proposition is either true or false; there are no degrees of it; also, I find that the word *truer* does not sit comfortably on the lips.

These could easily be dismissed, however, as personal obsessions.  So ignore them.  The more important reason for preferring 'more true to life' is because the phrase *true to life* works together, like a sort of compound adjective.  Its comparative is better expressed my using the comparative modifier 'more', because it can apply more easily to the entire phrase.

Beware, however.  Either will do and what I am offering is a personal view.  For that reason, it will probably be ruled 'off topic'.

Comment: Then if it's an accepted way of putting it, I guess it's alright to use it in a formal academic level article. Right? Is anyone going to point fingers at me for that?

Comment: @FriendlyFella No one will point a finger.